# What does invalidate method do?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What does `invalidate` method do in `winform` app?

`Invalidate()` **method** comes with **six overloaded** form inside `control class` of `System.Windows.Forms` **namespace**.

Thanks.....

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Windows Forms uses GDI for rendering. GDI is the original graphics interface in Windows. DirectX is a newer interface originally created for games development but now also used by higher level frameworks like WPF.

GDI is based around the concept of a paint method. When a window is displayed Windows will send a paint message to the code responsible for the window. This will lead to the paint method being called. The paint method should then paint the contents of the window onto the screen.

When a GDI program wants to update what is displayed *it cannot directly paint the updated image onto the screen*. Instead it has to tell Windows that an area needs to be updated. This is called **invalidating** a region. Windows will then call the relevant paint method supplying information about what is **invalid** and needs updating. The paint method should then draw the updated contents to the screen.

This method of updating screen contents is also used when windows are dragged across other windows. When GDI was developed graphics hardware was pretty slow and a lot of work is done inside Windows to cache bitmaps and to only invalidate and update what is changed.

When overlapping windows or child windows are drawn it is done back to front to get the correct layering of visual elements. This can lead to flicker where a background is erased and drawn followed by other elements in front. If the redraw speed is slower than the screen refresh you might notice some flickering. This is a telltale sign of a GDI application perhaps created using Windows Forms.

In Windows Forms when you **invalidate** a control you request that it should be **redrawn**.

Comment: very clean answer thank you so much for clearing me...i like the following words of your answer      =>"  about what is invalid and needs updating ."

Comment: Actually Paint is not part of GDI but of the Windows architecture.

Comment: @Henk Holterman: You are right. What I'm explaining is a really short story about GDI (graphics device interface) + USER (the user interface including windows management and message passing).

Comment: your explanation ("GDI is based around the concept of a paint method") is confusing Windows and GDI all over the place. Example: GDI is used for printing too and then there is no Paint or Invalidate involved.

Comment: One gotcha on my side is: If you do stuff in a Handler - like MouseMove and your stuff is fast, Invalidate causes the control to be up to data near all time. If however you do stuff that exceeds like 10ms - calling Invalidate() does not cause a redraw near real time but only after Mouse events slow down. It helps to then issue an Update() to force a re-draw. The cause seems to lie in the dispatcher and dispatch priorities. Draw is highest, Mouse-events folow and invalidate is lowest. Computing longer causes congestion (seems like it)

Answer (score 6):

Asks windows to redraw the client area of the invalidated window.

From MSDN:

"Invalidates the entire surface of the control and causes the control to be redrawn."

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/598t492a.aspx

Comment: could you please give me exact meaning of "Invalidates the entire surface" means what? as because my English is not much better  Thanks ..

Comment: @Aryan: In other words, invalidate here means the way it looks "needs updating."

Comment: It does not _force_. It _requests_ a repaint.

Comment: @All,  as per i interpret (tell me if it is wrong), invalid the current area to make it valid redraw it again

Comment: @Henk Gotcha. I could see that being an important detail. I'll edit.

Answer (score 3):

It causes the control to be repainted.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invalidate.aspx

You will rarely need to call this method unless you are doing some low level graphics manipulation.

Answer (score 2):

The Invalidate() method will redraw the control. For example if you use a panel 'panel1', which contains a label and a text box, the following code will redraw both the label and text box (by calling the Paint event)

```
panel1.Invalidate();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a GUI rendering method - it forces windows to redraw the visible portion of the control.

Comment: It does not _force_. It _requests_ a repaint.

Comment: Fair enough - I should remember that windows doesn't like to take orders. ;)

Answer (score 1):

It basically calls the PaintBackground and Paint methods of the control.

Comment: No. They are called from the MsgLoop