# How do you create buttons on a form through a method created in a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, button

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons based on what number of rows and columns the user enters and my method that creates the grid isn't working. When I call it the grid doesn't get created.

The method is inside my TileClass and I'm trying to call it in my GameBoard form. I feel like I'm not using the class properly. I don't think I'm calling the method correctly because I'm thinking this should work.

[This is what the form looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEsPn.png)

```
  class TileClass : Button
{
    public const int LEFT = 20;
    public const int WIDTH = 50;
    public const int HEIGHT = 50;
    public const int TOP = 50;
    public const int VGAP = 30;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int column;
    public int row;
    private int incomingRow;
    private int incomingColumn;

    public int IncomingRow { get => incomingRow; set => incomingRow = value; }
    public int IncomingColumn { get => incomingColumn; set => incomingColumn = value; }

    public TileClass()
    {

    }
    public void CreateGrid()
    {
        x = LEFT;
        y = TOP;
        column = IncomingColumn;
        row = IncomingRow;

        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
            {
                Button b = new Button();
                b.Left = x;
                b.Top = y;
                b.Width = WIDTH;
                b.Height = HEIGHT;
                b.Text = j.ToString();

                x += VGAP + HEIGHT;
                this.Controls.Add(b); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gameboard Form

```
 public partial class GameBoard : Form
{
    TileClass tileClass = new TileClass();

    public GameBoard()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void txtEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tileClass.IncomingColumn = int.Parse(txtColumn.Text);
        tileClass.IncomingRow = int.Parse(txtRow.Text);
        tileClass.CreateGrid();

    }
```

Comment: What does it mean `not working`? You have a new class inheriting from button class and method of it creates more buttons inside it. You shouldn't inherit the class from button. It should be inherited from a control such a panel or groupbox.

Comment: Wow, you go to all this trouble to parse the values for and store `IncomingCollumn` and `IncomingRow`, and then pass those to fields and then to local variables... and then you don't do anything with them. Don't you think your `for` loop should look at the row and column counts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot to do to make it happen:

```
class TileClass : Panel
{
...
    public int IncomingRow {get; set;}
    public int IncomingColumn { get; set; }
...
}
```

and remove:

```
private int incomingRow;
private int incomingColumn;
```

and the ideal approach would be using ResumeLayout before adding buttons and let the Gameboard form to be redrawn by calling Invalidate. [What does invalidate method do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425161/what-does-invalidate-method-do)
note: try col=100, row=100 with and without ResumeLayout&Invalidate

```
public partial class GameBoard : Form
{
    public GameBoard ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tileClass.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(tileClass);
    }

    TileClass tileClass = new TileClass();

    private void txtEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        tileClass.IncomingColumn = int.Parse(txtColumn.Text);
        tileClass.IncomingRow = int.Parse(txtRow.Text);

        this.ResumeLayout(); //Important
        tileClass.CreateGrid();
        this.Invalidate(); // Important
    }
}
```

and you can set more properties like, it needs more than this:

```
//tileClass.Location = new Point(10, 10); // not sure
tileClass.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
//tileClass.Size = new Size(200, 200); // not sure
```

and instead of j < 5 you should use col and row:

```
for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < column; j++)
    {
        Button b = new Button();
        b.Left = x;
        b.Top = y;
        b.Width = WIDTH;
        b.Height = HEIGHT;
        b.Text = string.Format("({0},{1})" , i, j);

        x += VGAP + HEIGHT;
        this.Controls.Add(b);
    }
    x = LEFT; // not sure, plz calculate!
    y += Top * (i+1); // not sure, plz calculate!
}
```

Comment: Pleasure. note that you need to use column and row values

Comment: Oh yea I know that, i had them there before i just removed them when I was trying to get it to work and never put them back